# Prolog "don't-care" variable

Tags: prolog

In prolog, is there any way to make a variable an instance of _? I'm making a sudoku solver, and I represent the puzzle read in by either numbers (given numbers) or -'s, (numbers not given). So, I read the whole puzzle into a list of lists, and now I want to pass that list to a function, and I need for '-' to be passed as _. Is there some way when I'm reading input to store the input as a _? Like for example..

```
get_next(X) :-
  repeat,
  get_char(Y),
  (Y = '\n' -> fail
   ;
   Y = '-' -> X = _
   ;
   X = Y
  ).
```

Something like this? I thought perhaps passing a `'_'` would do it, but of course, `'_' \= _` ... Any help would be greatly appreciated. Prolog is very foreign to me.

Comment: An underscore in Prolog is a variable that does not unify with other variables of the same name. That is its only difference from other named variables.

Comment: So, If I call `all_different([1,_,2,5,_,4,_,8,7])`, it is true, but when I use the above function to read the input, and do `all_different(Input)` it treats Input as `[1,_G#,2,5,_G# ... ]` and I get the error message `ERROR: >/2: Arithmetic: `2/0' is not a function`. What can I do to fix this? Implement my own all_different?

Comment: What I meant was that `all_different([1,_,2,5,_,4,_,8,7])` and `all_different([1,A,2,5,B,4,C,8,7])` is the same as long as you do not try unifying `A`, `B`, or `C` in other places in your rule.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just don't bind X with Y when Y='-'. That will leave X uninstantiated (provided it was uninstantiated in the first place):

```
get_next(X) :-
  repeat,
  get_char(Y),
  (Y = '\n' -> fail
   ;
   Y \= '-' -> X = Y  ; true
  ).
```

Comment: The repeat needs to happen, cause otherwise, '\n' becomes the first elem of the next row, so that loop skips over the '\n's. Anyways, when I do this code, I get the same results if I were to have bound `X = _`. Are we doing it wrong? Your answer makes sense, but it doesn't seem to work like one would think.

Comment: You should give us more details of your problem. The code given in this answer will leave X unbounded if the character received is a dash.